# Effects of a Resistor

Tags: voltage, current, resistors, kirchhoffs-laws

With this question I would like to clarify an understanding of resistors.
I have built these two schematics and performed a test.
Lighting the particular LED I use in this experiment
 directly with 1.5V produces no light at all,
 and lighting it directly with 3V lights it well.

[image: great resistor experiment]
I conclude the LED does not light with 1.5V
 for that is not enough voltage to open the diode's 'gate' at all, 
 yet the LED in "Schematic 2" is very dimly lit.
Measuring voltage between point A and B in "Schematic 1" reads 1.5V.
 Some may say by Kirchhoff's laws that is the voltage dropped by the resistor.
If the resistors actually 'drop' voltage this way, why does the LED light?
Is it safe to conclude the resistors only reduce current to the LED in this fashion
 and do not effect voltage to the LED?
Is 3V provided to the LED in "Schematic 2"?

I have created another one of these experiments.
Now, with a 10K and a 1M resistor, this LED (the green portion of an RGB) remains lit.
This LED still will not light on a single 1.5V AA.

[image: second experiment]

I think using the classic needle voltmeter is giving an invalid reading.
Using an oscilloscope on difference mode at 1V a division,
I measure 2V on the LED (between B and C) no matter what resistors I use.
Measuring the resistors (between A and B, C and D)
 the sum of their voltage is about 1V, in the case of the photo,
 the 1M drops most of the 1V.
On the other schematic with the 1K's, both dropped about 0.5V

Do resistors drop a constant voltage upon completing a circuit and then only drop current from then on as resistance is increased?

The only voltage drop here to me seems directly caused by the diode.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is far from clear to me. Your first schematic doesn't even show an LED. I will try to explain how everything works without any mysticism.

Resistors have two terminals, and they enforce a rule between those two terminals.

The rule is called "Ohm's law." Mathematically, the rule is V = I * R.

V is the voltage across the resistor.
I is the current flowing through the resistor.
R is the characteristic value of the resistor, normally measured in units called "Ohm's." Your resistors are 1k, so V = I * 1000.

Diodes are more complicated, so I am going to give you a simplified model. Assuming voltage polarity on the diode is correct (forward bias) the rule enforced by the diode is approximately V = K. (K is a constant). However, if the circuit is not capable of supplying that voltage across the diode, then it will enforce a different rule: I = 0. The constant, K, depends on the type of diode.

For an LED, any time I > 0, it may be emitting light. Red LED's are especially sensitive, and will emit light when even a tiny current is flowing.

A voltage supply also enforces the rule V = constant, normally by supplying current from its + terminal.

You put all these rules together, and hopefully everything will make sense. What circuits do is find the one unique solution to all the various rules. Sometimes the solution conditions cause the diode current (and light) to be zero. One way to check is to remove the diode from the circuit, then solve it. If V where the diode is supposed to go is > K for that diode, then the diode is in forward bias, and you need to put it back in and solve for the circuit assuming the voltage at that node is K.

Hope this makes some sense.

Comment: Yes, this makes some sense.

Comment: I am still unsettled about the resistors reducing voltage. Here is what I am observing. I measure the voltage between B and C without the diode or short and read 3V. If placing the LED in to complete the circuit causes the resistors to drop a total of about 1.2V why wont the LED light at all directly to 1.5V? Since I supply 3V, I see constant voltage and variable current as I alter resistance. such as this: I = 3V / R, so in Schematic 1, 3/2000 = 0.0015amps and if resistance is changed, 3/1000000 = 0.000003amps. How am I not finding voltage drop correctly?

Comment: Voltage between B and C without a short is 3V, because current = 0, so voltage drop = 0. That seems correct. Now you add the LED, and each resistor has 0.6V across it? So the LED has 1.8V? Did you confirm with meter? If so, the LED is passing 1.2/2000 = 0.6 mA. This may not be enough to make the LED glow. Double check everything.

Comment: Indeed, the LED still glows. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Resistors do drop voltage - but the voltage across a resistor is determined by the current through it - as calculated by Ohm's Law.  Also, by Ohm's Law, the current through a resistor is determined by the voltage across it.

In your circuit 1, with two 1K resistors across a 3 volt battery, you have 3 volts across a 2000 ohm resistance so the current in the circuit will be I = E/R = 3/2000 = .0015 Amp, or 1.5 mA.

In circuit 2, you still have 2K resistance in the circuit, but the LED will (for a typical red LED) drop about 1.8 volts.  (This voltage drop will increase slightly with increasing current.)  In this circuit, the total voltage across the two resistors will be the battery voltage, 3 volts, minus the LED voltage, 1.8 volts, or about 1.2 volts.  The current through the circuit will then be 1.2/2000 = .0005 Amp, or 0.5 mA, which will barely light the LED.

If you connect the LED directly to your 3 volt battery, without a resistor, the LED will try to draw enough current to reduce the battery voltage to the LED voltage, and will probably die in the attempt.  Batteries do have an internal resistance that varies with the state of charge or age of the battery - if the battery's internal resistance is high enough, the LED may survive for a while.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Indeed, the LED barely lights. I agree the diode drops voltage in some way I have yet to understand and I agree without the resistors the LED would draw too much current, but I am targeting the resistors in this question. Do the resistors drop voltage in the equation, or is only the LED dropping voltage? Suppose the 2 1k's are either 0 ohms or 1 million ohms, will 3 volts still be provided between B and C to the LED?

Comment: In circuit 2, with 0.5 mA, and 1.8 volts across the LED, each resistor will drop about 0.6 volts, so the total voltage drop in the resistors and LED will equal the battery voltage (to comply with Kirchoff's Voltage Law).  Changing the resistor values will change the current in the circuit, and the voltage dropped across the resistors.

Comment: It does not appear to change the voltage dropped across the resistors upon changing their values.